# add to global list of symbols using user input lisp

Tags: lisp

I am using SBCL REPL:

with the function:

```
 (defun add-from-list (word) 
    (setf (symbol-value word) '())
    (push  word *vocab*))
```

I can

```
> (add-from-list 'dog)
```

my global list `*vocab*` then looks like this:

```
> (dog)
```

I can add animals all day and the list gets longer. I can give the animals associative arrays and do lots of fun stuff with them.

But now I want to add an animal from user input I have tried many different things especially  `(intern (read-line))` until I have baffled myself. the closest I ever got was something that looked like

```
> (|snake|)
```

and when i try to use it like the other animals it says it is unbound.

1. what does it mean when its got the `|`s around it?
2. how can I possibly add another animal to my global list `*vocab*` using a user input like `read-line`?

Answer (score 2):

`|` is used to escape symbols that contain special characters.

In this case, it's because the symbol name contains lower-case letters. By default, when you type a symbol, the letters are converted to uppercase, e.g. when you type `foo`, it reads as the symbol `FOO`. This allows you to write code case-insensitively, e.g. you can write `(defun ...)` or `(DEFUN ...)` and they'll both work.

But this is only done when reading input. Functions like `INTERN` use the name literally. Since the printer tries to print symbols such that reading them back in will return the same symbol, it escapes the name if it contains lowercase letters to ensure this consistency.

If you want to process the user input the way the reader does, you can use `READ-FROM-STRING` after calling `READ-LINE`.

```
(let ((word (read-from-string (read-line))))
    ...
)
```

Or you could call `STRING-UPCASE`:

```
(let ((word (intern (string-upcase (read-line)))))
    ...
)
```

However, this is less portable, because the automatic upcasing is a readtable-specific setting that can be customized (see [`READTABLE-CASE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rdtabl.htm)). Using `READ-FROM-STRING` ensures that you get whatever the current setting is.

Comment: thanks so mush for the though out response. It solved my problem. I noticed you have helped me several times. Ive been reading a lot of books on lisp and even though I am still quite murky about some basic concepts, with the little I do understand, I am still able to do some exciting things. thanks again Barmer.   Gregg